# How to check if my debugger's program counter is inside a function?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dwarf

I'm writing a debugger and want to see if its program counter is inside a function. I guess I need to check that it's between `DW_AT_low_pc` and `DW_AT_high_pc`. Here's the code I'm trying to debug:

```
void myPrint()
{
    int test_a = 3;
    int test_b = 2;

    printf( "myPrint: sum: %d\n", test_a + test_b );
}

int main( void )
{
    myPrint();

    return 0;
}
```

`dwarfdump` gives the following:

```
< 1><0x0000033d>    DW_TAG_subprogram
                      DW_AT_external              yes(1)
                      DW_AT_name                  myPrint
                      DW_AT_decl_file             0x00000001 /home/glaze/Documents/src/debugger/test_input.c
                      DW_AT_decl_line             0x0000000d
                      DW_AT_decl_column           0x00000006
                      DW_AT_low_pc                0x00001181
                      DW_AT_high_pc               <offset-from-lowpc>66
                      DW_AT_frame_base            len 0x0001: 9c: DW_OP_call_frame_cfa
                      DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites yes(1)
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x0000037a>
```

In my debugger loop I read the program counter as follows:

```
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    if (ptrace( PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs ) == -1)
    {
        printf( "%s", strerror( errno ) );
        return 1;
    }

    Elf64_Addr programCounter = regs.rip;
```

But it gets values that are never between `DW_AT_low_pc` and `DW_AT_high_pc`, like `0x7f9b94c95100`.

I can already programmatically read `DW_AT_low_pc` and `DW_AT_high_pc` inside my debugger program and it reports the same values as `dwarfdump`.

How do I check that my program counter is inside `myPrint` function?

Comment: What values DO you get? And what's the base address of your executable?

Comment: @ssbssa myPrint's low_pc is `0x00001181`. I read the base address by taking the address in the first line of `pmap -x pid` and it's `0000555555554000`. But my program counter never has values near the base address, it's always something like `0x7ffff7ecf1e7`.

Comment: And what does `info files` in gdb say?

Comment: @ssbssa `info files` tells me that the entry point is `0x555555555060`.

Comment: But does it show you where `0x7ffff7ecf1e7` belongs to?

Comment: @ssbssa I guess it's inside .text segment: `0x00007ffff7fd0100 - 0x00007ffff7ff25e4 is .text in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. So I seem to be only getting addresses inside some libraries, not my executable.

Comment: I think if your program actually did something that takes some time, you will get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by taking the program's base address by reading the first line of `/proc/pid/maps` and adding it to `DW_AT_low_pc`. `DW_AT_high_pc` is an offset from `DW_AT_low_pc`.

Then in my debugger loop I ran it single-stepped with

```
ptrace( PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, pid, NULL, NULL );
```

At each iteration, I checked that the program counter `regs.rip` is between the function address range.

Debugging the issue was easier when I compiled the test program with `-g -fno-pic -O0 -fPIE` and in the debugger program disabled address space randomization by calling `personality( ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE );` just before `ptrace( PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL );`. I also made the test program more complex by writing a simple adding loop so that it does also something else than calling library routines like `printf()` whose addresses are outside of my executable.